# How do i select from this table of mine to display only once the data even there is multiple of them?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 question_id  question_text   field_name     lo_category             lo_domain  
      1        Build a tree     Build        Application             Cognitive 
      2        Build a tree     Build        Origination             Psychomotor 
      3        Build a tree     Build        Complex overt response  Psychomotor 
      4        describe the..  describe      Knowledge               Cognitive
```

How do i select from this table to display only question_text that is not the same ? 
It is actually a search result that i have to store in this table."Build a tree" is entered once but there is 3 results.So i want to know the number of questions entered and also display the questions entered from this table.

```
 EG
    Questions
    Build a tree
    describe the..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY question_text;
```

But the problem is that, the first row with same name will be first display.

If you want to get only the question_text. You can do it either of this.

```
SELECT question_text FROM table GROUP BY question_text;

SELECT DISTINCT(question_text) FROM table;
```